# C++ Linear search algorithm

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a linear search algorithm on c++ but I am having some trouble with my linearSearch function in my code. It is a simple for loop and I can't see what seems to be the problem, I ask the user to enter a key and if it is the a key within the array then it should give the correct position but it does not. Can anyone see where I am went wrong in my implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int linearSearch(int arr[],int size, int key){
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    if(key == arr[i]){
        return i;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
  }
}


int main() {
 const int size = 20;
 int numbers[size];
 srand((unsigned) time(0));
 for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    numbers[i] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    cout << numbers[i] << " ";
 }
 cout << endl;
 int key;
 cout << "Enter a key to search for: " << endl;
 cin >> key;
 int retValue = linearSearch(numbers,size,key);
 if(retValue >= 0){
     cout << "Key found at position " << retValue << endl;
 }else{
     cout << "Key not found" << endl;
 }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just FWIW, `std::find` already provides a linear search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(key == arr[i]){
     return i;
 }else{
     return -1;
 }
```

You return either i or -1 after the first comparison, so the rest of the array is never searched at all.  You should remove the `else return -1` clause and `return -1` only at the end of the function, instead.

If you do this the `linearSearch` function should look like:

```
int linearSearch(int arr[],int size, int key){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if(key == arr[i]){
           return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: In addition he may not even be calling `linearSearch()` with a value which exists.  He generated 20 random numbers on [0,100] but the code does not inspect the array.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The array is printed as it is filled.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I am a Java guy so have some patience.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer, can you explain more?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 step though the execution of the linearSearch() function, either in a debugger or on a piece of paper, and you'll see what happens.  In particular you'll see that the for loop never loops, because no matter what the if-statement does, you always return from the function during the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Wolfgang-1: You only want to return "not found" if you've iterated through the _entire array_ and none of the comparisons succeed. That's why you should return -1 outside the `for` loop (after its completed).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your linearSearch function is that it returns -1 (not found) just after the first comparison if does not match. It does not search through the full array.

Try the following code, that searchs backwards and stops when a coincidence is found or the "bottom" of the array is passed (i equals to -1). It returns the current value of i, which can be into the array if a coincidende was met or -1 if nothing happened during the search.

```
int linearSearch(int arr[], int size, int key){
    int i;
    for(i = size-1; i >= 0 && key != arr[i]; --i);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int linearSearch(int array[], int n,int searchKey){

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        if(searchKey==array[i]){
        return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Comment: You should format your code correctly. Also, please write *how* this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int linearSearch(int arr[], int size, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i]==key) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

problem is you are either returning `i` or `-1` else nothing. code will exit after returning those two. and i also think that `retValue` also be incremented with `1` to have the correct postion.